# how big hello.gram file be in sphinx java

Tags: java, speech-to-text, cmusphinx

I am new to sphinx java and started with small project of employee details.Download HelloWorld program and modifying it. how to get employee id (eg : T5438,Y7651,U9085) and department ( Auto, Support , Mobile) dynamically.

How to declare below in Hello.gram file :

```
public <greet> = ();
```

I want to know how and what words i have to add in hello.gram and how to do it dynamically

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is your .GRAM abnf or grxml ?

Comment: i want to convert speech into text only. When employee says his id we have to recognize and print the same.

Comment: i give values like public <greet> = (One | Two | Three | Four | Five | Six | Seven | Eight | Nine | Zero );

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try something like below :

```
public <basicCmd> = <startPolite> <command> <endPolite>;

<command> = <action> <object>;
<action> = /10/ open |/2/ close |/1/ delete |/1/ move;
<object> = [the | a] (window | file | menu);
```

Answer (score 2):

Unless your IDs have some recurrent pattern, there's no way to add them dynamically. In this case you will have to make a list of them beforehand and make the corresponding grammar. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33027132/1746434) on how to make grammar for recurrent IDs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Alexander . can you please help me how to do for department ? how to add in hello.gram. No clear tutorials available on net.

Comment: The link that I provided in the answer gives quit clear example of how to compose the grammar and http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialsphinx4 will help you to run it.